# NodeJS and Mysql. Would not calling connection.end() before terminate be acceptable?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use mysql from AWS Lambda (hosted nodejs).

The nodejs instance will be automatically terminated by Lambda when no new request show up for a few minutes.
Due to this Lambda behavior, I don't want to call end() because otherwise it would turn every request doing connect-use-end cycle. I want the connection (or pool) to live over multiple requests.

Would that be a problem if connection.end() is not called and instance get terminated? (could there be leak or something)

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

index.handler = function(){

    connection.query('SELECT x', function(err, rows, fields) {
        // do something here
    });
};


// * cannot call because potential incoming request still need to use.
// connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may endup getting "Too many connection" errors at somepoint.

Your best option till then is to open and close connection within the same invocation.

Connection pool is a use case which needs effective reuse of lamdba containers and is a pending feature request on aws.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216000